# Is it possible to isolate p in $"a = 2bpq + 2apq + a(p^2) + 2aqq + bqq"?$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is it possible to simplify this equation so that $p$ is isolated on one side instead of $a$? I tried factoring out $p$ on the right side, but I get stuck with the $ap^2$.

$$a = 2bpq + 2apq + ap^2 + 2aq^2 + bq^2$$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By solving p in this equation you get:

$p = \frac{\sqrt{a^2(-q)^2+a^2+abq^2+b^2q^2} -aq - bq}{a}$

or

$p = \frac{-\sqrt{a^2(-q)^2+a^2+abq^2+b^2q^2} -aq - bq}{a}$

EDIT:

Steps as requested:

$ap^2+2apq+2bpq+2aq^2+bq^2=a$

$p^2 + \frac{p(2aq+2bq)}{a }+ \frac{2aq^2+bq^2}{a} = 1$

$p^2 + \frac{p(2aq+2bq)}{a} = 1 - \frac{2aq^2+bq^2}{a}$

$p^2 + \frac{p(2aq+2bq)}{a} + \frac{(2aq+2bq)^2}{4a^2} = 1 + \frac{(2aq+2bq)^2}{4a^2} - \frac{2aq^2+bq^2}{a}$

$(p + \frac{(2aq+2bq)}{2a})^2 = 1 + \frac{(2aq+2bq)^2}{4a^2} - \frac{2aq^2+bq^2}{a}$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Do you mind sharing the steps on how you got it? Thanks!

Comment: I was going to mention yes it is just a dressed up quadratic equation, just collect everything on one side with like powers of p and identify the quadratic coefficients A B and C

Comment: no problem steps will be edited in the answer in 2 minutes (i need to copy them from paper to computer)

Answer (score 0):

$$a = 2bpq + 2apq + ap^2 + 2aq^2 + bq^2$$
$$ap^2+p(2bq + 2aq) + (2aq^2 + bq^2-a)=0$$
It is  a quadratic equation of $p$.

for $ax^2+bx+c=0\;$

$x=\dfrac{-b\pm\sqrt{b^2-4\cdot a\cdot c}}{2a}$

similarly:

$$p=\dfrac{-(2bq + 2aq)\pm\sqrt{(2bq + 2aq)^2-4\cdot a\cdot (2aq^2 + bq^2-a)}}{2a}$$

I hope you can solve from here